# image on homepage disappeared due to change of permalink name

Tags: php, permalinks, homepage, icon, settings-api

where to do this in Wordpress backend?
I need to add the missing icons for "Smart living" and "Smart workspace" on homepage section - image is not in available in Media - It is in a section of the homepage. It is there for "Smart care" see attached image
[image: section.jpg]

or look at website via https://www.ipbuilding.be/en/

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click and Inspect Element you will see it is supposed to be inside an SVG file on your website, but if you open the SVG file the "smart-living" and "smart-workspace" parts are missing. Normally this type of file is either inside of a theme or a plugin but whoever set it up placed it in the root of your website. You should contact the developer who created your theme, or if that's not possible, you'll need to either re-create the missing parts of the SVG, or else edit your theme's `front-page.php` file and point it to a .png or .jpg version.